# Applying jquery code only to mobile and tablet

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to apply this jquery code only for mobile and tablets

```
<script>
  jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
var y = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
if (y > 440) {
jQuery('.dropdown,.navbar.fixed-top').fadeIn(600);
} else {
jQuery('.dropdown,.navbar.fixed-top').fadeOut(600);
}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to grab the window width and run the function if the width is smaller than a certain width.

```
<script>
  jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    if(jQuery(window).width() <= 1024){
       var y = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
       if (y > 440) {
         jQuery('.dropdown,.navbar.fixed-top').fadeIn(600);
       } else {
         jQuery('.dropdown,.navbar.fixed-top').fadeOut(600);
       }
  });
}
</script>
```